# Hisrc for responsive images doesn't seem to be working

Tags: jquery, image, mobile, responsive-design

I would like to use the hisrc method for displaying responsive images depending on the bandwidth of the user.
I have test my file on my desktop on also on my iphone 4s and it is still just displaying the default smaller src image rather than the larger image. Can you see anything in my code that might be the reason why it's not working? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN"
"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml"/>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True" />
<title>Gifts</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="xhtml2gradientjava1.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="hisrc.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.hisrc.speedTest();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".products").hisrc(); 
}
</script>
</head>


<body>

<div id="content">

    <img class="products centre" src="images/bracelet_opt.jpg" data-1x="images/br0266_300x300.jpg" data-2x="images/br0266_300x300.jpg" />
       <div class="box_desc"><h3>Silver Beaded Heart Bracelet</h3><p>Ref: #BD0266</p>
          <div class="description">
          <h4>Description</h4>
            <p>Beaded Heart Bracelet by Newbridge Silverware. Silver plated heart detail bracelet with a protective anti tarnish layer, presented in a Newbridge Silverware gift box.</p> <h5>Dimensions:</h5> <p>240mm in length and 5mm in width.</p>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Also I was wondering do I need to include both data-1x and data-2x as for some of the images 300x300 is the largest I have. This site will be directed towards mobile phones, but not tablets or ipads. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".products").hisrc(); 
} // missing );
```

Comment: Yes I see. That works perfect now. I knew it was probably something simple. I'm only new to javascript. :P :) Thanks for the help :)